# using case to select multiple conditions

Tags: sql, sql-server

This is my SQL table

```
RecordID      RecordState     Time
-----------------------------------
record1       failed          9:10
record2       failed          9:20
record2       passed          9:30
```

this is my query.

```
select RecordID, max(RecordState)
from RecordTable a
group by RecordID
```

For the record  `record2`  the value was first failed and then passed so max(recordstate) for this record is passed

```
RecordID      RecordState     Time
-----------------------------------
record1       failed          9:10
record2       passed          9:30
```

Now here is a different scenario

```
  RecordID      RecordState     Time
-----------------------------------
record1       failed          9:10
record2       failed          9:20
record2       passed          9:30
record2       failed          9:40
```

at 9:40 the record failed again so my final output should be

```
RecordID      RecordState     Time
-----------------------------------
record1       failed          9:10
record2       failed          9:40
```

however since I am using Max(RecordState) it will always return 'passed' I need to somehow also check for the latest time and display fail in this case (9:40).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `ROW_NUMBER()`, and `order by Time DESC`

**[SQL DEMO](http://rextester.com/FBKL57253)**

```
SELECT RecordID, RecordState, Time
FROM ( SELECT RecordID, RecordState, Time,
              ROW_NUMBER() over (PARTITION BY RecordID      
                                 ORDER BY Time DESC) as rn
       FROM YourTable
      ) T
WHERE T.rn =1
```

**OUTPUT**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

this gonna count the rows that has same cells and then take the last by the date

```
select * from  
(
select *,
       row_number()over(partition by RecordID order by time desc) as rn 
from RecordTable
) A
Where RN = 1 and RecordState = 'Failed'
```

Comment: OP desire to show the latest `recordState` not just the `Failed`

Comment: (partition by RecordID order by time desc) will create the partition with rn. and then we take only rowns where rn = 1 (the letest one)